# Find perfect squares in range

Tags: java

I've just taken the codility test on finding perfect squares in a range. I thought it was pretty straightforward, but on submitting, I got that a 50% on correctness and 66% on performance.

The spec also mentioned that range will be between [-2147483648 ... 2147483647], expected worst-case time complexity is `O(sqrt(abs(B)))` and expected worst-case space complexity is O(1).

This is my code:

### Solution1.java

```
public class Solution1 {

    public int solution(int A, int B) {
        int upperLimit = (int) Math.sqrt(B);
        int squares = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= upperLimit; i++) {
            if (i * i >= A && i * i <= B) {
                squares++;
            }
        }
        return squares;
    }
}
```

### Solution1Test.java

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class Solution1Test {

    private final Solution1 solution1 = new Solution1();

    @Test
    public void given4_17_return3() {
        assertEquals(3, solution1.solution(4, 17));
    }

    @Test
    public void given1_17_return4() {
        assertEquals(4, solution1.solution(1, 17));
    }

    @Test
    public void given1_35_return5() {
        assertEquals(5, solution1.solution(1, 35));
    }

    @Test
    public void given1_36_return6() {
        assertEquals(6, solution1.solution(1, 36));
    }

    @Test
    public void given9_49_return5() {
        assertEquals(5, solution1.solution(9, 49));
    }

    @Test
    public void given3000_3300_return3() {
        assertEquals(3, solution1.solution(3000, 3300));
    }
}
```

I'm specially concerned (and confused) about the 50% on correctness.

PS: it this is off-topic just let me know and I'll ask on stackoverflow.

Comment: _"I'm specially concerned (and confused) about the 50% on correctness."_ What does that mean?

Comment: You tell us whether it fits all the criteria of [on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Raystafarian Why should this question not be on-topic? The author clearly stated that he thought the task was pretty straightforward and is therefore confused about receiving only 50% on correctness. Thus, the code works correctly *to the best of the author's knowledge*.

Comment: @Stingy the author mentioned they would remove it if it was not on topic, I was just providing a resource. I didn't vote to close

Comment: @Raystafarian Ah yes, excuse me. For some reason, I was reading suspicion of the question being off-topic due to the code not working correctly into your comment, possibly because of πάντα ῥεῖ's comment above yours.

Comment: @Stingy Just to clarify: I neither close voted at a 1st hit (which is rare). I just asked what they mean regarding those 50% correctness/incorrectness. That just sounds fishy and the OP didn't care to clarify that yet.

Comment: _@antonro_ If that site tells you there is 50% correctness, that could well mean your code simply fails another 50% of their test cases. It's hard to tell, without knowing the  test cases, and such makes it even harder to review your code for improvements.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I also don't know the test cases

Comment: Your question is being discussed on Meta [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8809/code-that-handles-n-of-test-cases-but-not-all). According to [the first answer provided](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8810/139640), 50% is not good enough, and the code should be considered broken.

Comment: @Coal_ Thanks for letting me know. Having read the answer there, I don't fully understand why has my question been put on hold; I did add unit tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only reasons I can think of that your code was deemed incorrect are that it doesn't consider 0 as a perfect square, and that you don't consider the possibility that `B < A` (although maybe the test defined `B` as being greater than or equal to `A` and this is not a negligence of you). As for the performance, here are some suggestions:

- You don't need to check `i * i <= B` in the loop, because the termination condition of the `for` loop already required that `i <= upperLimit`, and with `i` being positive, there is no way that `i*i > B` if `i <= sqrt(B)`.
- Taking the above into account, it follows that once the loop reaches an `i` for which `i * i >= A`, there is no point in continuing the loop, because all future values of `i` will have squares that fall within the specified range.
- Continuing this trail of thought, it turns out that the solution can simply be expressed as `(int) (Math.floor(Math.sqrt(B)) - Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(Math.max(A, 0)))) + 1`, provided `B` is non-negative and `B >= A`. This expression doesn't really do anything your code doesn't do except floating point arithmetics. I don't know if two calls to `Math.sqrt()` (which delegates to `StrictMath.sqrt()`, which is a `native` method) are faster than using integer arithmetics in a loop, but it's definitely more to the point, coding-wise.